# javascript firestore TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' undefined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' undefined. I tried to get the **pr_cluster** of the document in firestore but there are error.

```
this.props.firebase.cartItems().doc(authUser.uid).collection('products').limit(1).onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
                
                
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                
                    this.state.pr_cluster = doc.data().pr_cluster;
                    
                    
                            });
                            
                
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an arrow function to avoid redefining `this` inside the forEach callback.

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    this.state.pr_cluster = doc.data().pr_cluster;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir